# how to get the user_ID for current wordpress user using MySQL only

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and mysql, and i have to setup a MySQL trigger to verify data entered into the logged in users profile.

The only way I can see is by setting up a trigger so that when wordpress tries to UPDATE the data in the MYSQL database, the trigger will fire allowing me to check the data before its updated.

However the data verification depends on which user is logged in, and i cant figure out how to find out the current user ID using MYSQL alone without PHP wp_get_current_user() since i cant call that from MySQL trigger procedure.

Anybody knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can't solve your issue without using MySQL triggers? One other way would be to setup a generic MySQL trigger which you could execute on the Wordpress side when the user modify his profile. Other than that why not just use PHP?

Comment: Musk, ok, how do i do that? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe "NEW.USER_ID" will be already filled in when the trigger hits?? Then i can just use that?

Answer (score 0):

there is already a function called `get_current_user_id()`

Else you have to implement a SQL-Query like "SELECT ID from $tablename WHERE username=?"

Comment: The problem is that username is not unique in the database, so it might get the wrong user i think sometimes.

Comment: @PaulMan  you can use email id to fetch the data.

Comment: Good idea, i will try that! Thanks!